# find last row data [for the particular]/[filtered by] year in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel I have data as below.

```
2011    0
2011    15
2011    10
2011    5
2012    15
2012    10
2012    5
```

What I want to find is the last row for the respective year so that the output would be

```
2011    5
2012    5
```

Any idea how to get this done?

I am looking at this [post](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Excel-1059/Find-filled-cell-column.htm) and found the way for finding last row data, however I need to know how to filter the same by year.

**Note**: I want to do this using excel pre-defined function. NO macro, NO coding, NO pivot.

---

### Edit 1

`=INDEX($B:$B,MAX(IF(LEN($B:$B)>0,ROW($B:$B),0)),1)` gives me answer 5. However I want it to fiter by year. Any idea how to get this done?

---

### Edit 2

`=OFFSET(B2,MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B25)),ROW(B2:B25),0))-ROW(B2),0)` this also gives last row data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
{=INDEX($B$1:$B$7,MAX(IF(A9=$A$1:$A$7,ROW($A$1:$A$7))))}
```

You **must** enter this as an array function, so enter copy and paste the code between the `{}`'s and then press `ctrl-shift-enter`. The code assumes you have `2011` in cell `A9`. If you then type 2012 in `A10` and copy the formula down it will work.

[image: Screen capture]

The basic idea of the formula is:

1. If any cell in `A1:A7` matches `A9`, add its row number to a list of candidate rows
2. Take the maximum row number of the list of candidates; say this is *k*
3. Use the index function to return the value that is in row *k* of `B1:B7`

Comment: yes this is what I was looking for... thanks for the answer... let me see and get back to you...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this *without coding* is by using [pivot tables](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/08/19/excel-pivot-tables-tutorial/).

If you did happen to write an excel formula or function for it you would most likely use the [max()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/max.php) function and the [vlookup()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php) or [hlookup()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/hlookup.php) functions.

Comment: I don't want to use pivot also... No handwork... Excel functions should only do everything.

Comment: also how max and vlookup would help me? example would be great