# print occurrences in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Lets say I have data as

```
2011
2012
2011
2012
2013
2013
2011
2012
```

Then what I want is

```
2011     1
2012     1
2011     2
2012     2
2013     1
2013     2
2011     3
2012     3
```

Any idea to get this done?

Note that I want to get this done using Excel formulaes only. NO MACRO NO PIVOT NO CODING.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use the following formula:

```
B1=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)
```

That's about it.

Paste down this formula and it will create the column with the counts.

Comment: thanks... this is what I was expected. :) You saved me... :) :)

Comment: can you also take a look at my [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138541/find-last-row-data-for-the-particular-filtered-by-year-in-excel) & [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136944/find-sum-in-different-way)